# How to select from multiple tables based on many to many relationship?

Tags: python, mysql, join, many-to-many

I am trying to create a select statement that will return a list of users following a specific user , based on conditions from two tables.  I have the following relationship created in my database. (incoming 10/10 ms paint skills)

[image: Table Design]

What I want to output for example , are the users following tim , (follower) , which have notifications set as 0 in the users table. 
From there I can do what I want programmatically with the results.

So far I have tried inner join,

```
SELECT users.username FROM users
INNER JOIN followers
ON users.username = followers.followed
WHERE followers.followed = users.username AND 
users.username = 'tim'
```

and I can't seem to figure out how to format it properly.

Comment: ok , editing incoming

Comment: i included the method I used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be much more cleaner if you use instead of the 'followed' string, the 'userid' and instead of the 'follower' the 'followerid'.

In this case would be userid=1 (tim user id) in followers table.

Then the query would be:

```
select * from users where notifications=0 and id in (select followerid from 
followers where userid=1)
```

If you need to stick to that structure:

```
select * from users where notifications=0 and username like (select follower from 
followers where followed like 'tim')
```

Comment: The problem with that is programmatically python is grabbing the person's username (it's a bot) , and taking that name and inserting it into the sql statement. So it would seem I would have to search the id up first that corresponds with the name it finds.

Comment: Ok , testing this now

Comment: What do you mean ? This gives the result you asked.

Comment: I switched out your * with username and it worked like a charm!! Thank you!